# Colours of variables are not there on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

The colours of my vscode when I edit python code do not have colour for variables anymore. But when I edit JavaScript code it does have the regular colours. How do I fix this?

This happened after I was playing around with JavaScipt for the first time.

On the python picture `what` is supposed to be red.

I tried to restart my computer and vscode
[python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNX0G.png)
[javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUQZp.png)

Comment: is your python extension enabled? did you select an interpreter yet?